# unable to execute update statement in while loop php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following query

```
$products = $this->mysqliengine->query("select * from temp_all_product where download_status = 0") or die($this->mysqliengine->error());
    $temp_status_update = $this->mysqliengine->prepare("update temp_all_product set download_status = ? where id = ?") or die($this->mysqliengine->error);
    $temp_status_update->bind_result($download_status, $id);

    while($product = $products->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $product['id'];
        $download_status = 1;
        $temp_status_update->execute();
    }
```

In the above statement I can select the values from `temp table` but unable to update the status. What is the problem here

Comment: Why not simply `UPDATE temp_all_product SET download_status = 1 WHERE download_status = 0`?

Comment: It will make trouble if I use limit in my sql query. right?

Comment: It will do what if you do what?

Comment: cant get you. can you please explain

Comment: Funny, that's exactly what I was asking you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use bind_param in your update statement instead of bind_result.

```
$temp_status_update->bind_param('dd', $download_status, $id);
```

The 'dd' just tells the system that each input is a number.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

@eggyal was merely suggesting that you could replace all your code with a single update statement.  Your remark about LIMIT does not make much sense.

Suggestion: If you don't have much invested in mysqli then switch to PDO.  It allows using named parameters which can make your code more robust and easier to maintain:

```
$sql = "UPDATE temp_all_product SET download_status = :status where id = :id";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array('status' => 1, 'id' => $product['id']));
```

Plus you can configure it to throw exceptions so you don't need all this error checking.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/